# FCM : click_action not working properly from Window 10 notification center

Tags: javascript, firebase, windows-10, firebase-cloud-messaging

I use Firebase notifications pretty extensively in my application. 
I just noticed that when you have a whole bunch of notification in the notification center on Windows 10 of the same origin, only one notification's click action will fire.

[image]

These notification contain exactly the same data, but only one click_action event will work and it's completely random as to which one will work.

```
notification request body: {
 "priority": "high",
  "registration_ids": ["tokens"],
   "notification": {
    "click_action": "https://somewebsite.com",
       "body": "Hello World",
    "title": "Wake n See",
    "sound" : "default",
    "content-available": 0

   },
  "data": {
    "is_silent" : "no"
  }
}
```

I have tried a whole bunch of ways to replicate this, like closing the website tab before clicking on the rest of the notification, or closing the browser after one click_action has fired.

Firebase version: 5.4.1 (also able to replicate this on 4.8.1)

Please help.

Comment: Any news on this? I'm having the same problem and I'm stuck :(

Comment: @JanW No i couldn't find any solutions.